# Laravel 5 - How to logout a user from all of his devices using Redis

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redis

I'm building a laravel application where A user logged in other device and While logged out I want to force him to logged out from other device also. How do I implement in laravel.

Personally I have used Redis Server. While running the program I have run `redis-server.exe` also.And I'm in Windows. 
I have changed the .env file also with `CACHE_DRIVER=redis SESSION_DRIVER=redis` 
Besides Redis already installed with laravel I have also installed `"predis/predis": "~1.0"`

And Here is my Controller where I have written the login for forcing the user from logged out from other device.

In Signin controller when I dd() the `$redis` I see the session created for that user but when I logged in and when going to logout I dd() the `$userSessions` But see empty so it means nothing stored in sessions table to compare.

If anyone find any solution please help me to find it out. Thanks In Advance.

Controller:

```
  public function postSignIn(Request $request)
  {       

   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' =>$request['password'] ]) ) {  
      $redis = \Redis::connection();   
      $userId = Auth::user()->id;
      $redis->sadd('users:sessions:' . $userId,Session::getId());      
      return redirect()->route('main');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}



public function getLogout()
{
    $redis = Redis::connection();
    $userId =Auth::user()->id;
    $userSessions = $redis->smembers('user:sessions:' . $userId);
    $redis->sadd('users:sessions:'.$userId,Session::getId());
    $currentSession = Session::getId();
    foreach ($userSessions as $sessionId) {
      if ($currentSession == $sessionId) {
        continue; 
      }
      $redis->srem('user:sessions:' . $userId, $sessionId);
      $redis->del('laravel:' . $sessionId);
      \Session::setId( $sessionId ); 
        \Session::clear();
    }
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('main');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Redis with Laravel You can use sth like this:

```
// During LogIn
Cache::tags(['sessions', auth()->id])->forever('session:'.auth()->id, Session::getId());

// Logout
Cache::tags([auth()->id])->flush();
```

Tags allows to You remove all keys stored with concrete tag.

**[Updated]**

You have to fit session variable names.

```
public function postSignIn(Request $request)
{

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' =>$request['password'] ]) ) {
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        \Cache::tags(['sessions', 'session_'.$userId])->forever('users:sessions:' . $userId, Session::getId());
        return redirect()->route('main');
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}



public function getLogout()
{
    $userId =Auth::user()->id;

    $sessionId = \Cache::get('users:sessions:' . $userId);
    \Cache::tags(['session_'.$userId])->flush();
    \Session::setId( $sessionId );
    \Session::clear();

    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('main');
}
```

Comment: How it will delete the sessions created while login in logout controller?
I have replaced with your code actually nothing  get changed actually.

Comment: I have changed with your code but nothing get changed actually thanks for helping though!